# How to implement Big Int in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, biginteger, largenumber, bignum

I am working on open-source project. It doesn’t properly meet its specs due to the representation as JavaScript numbers ie let,const... I want to add support for Int, Long Int, and Big Ints similar to c++.

Can anyone please suggest any resource or approach to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: How about using [BigInt values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) in modern implementations of JavaScript?

Comment: Hmmmm... how about the JavaScript `BigInt` function?

Comment: Any Idea of how BigInt is implemented behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has gained [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) support as a feature a couple of years ago. By now, most users have browsers new enough to support it: https://caniuse.com/bigint.

If you want to support even older browsers, there are a variety of pure JavaScript implementations with different pros and cons, for example [JSBI](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi), [MikeMcl's bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js), [Peter Olson's BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js), [Yaffle's BigInteger](https://github.com/Yaffle/BigInteger). You can study their sources to learn how they're implemented.

For learning about how native BigInt is implemented, [this V8 blog post](https://v8.dev/blog/bigint) gives some insight.

Side note: JavaScript is perfectly capable of expressing 32-bit integers à la C++ `int`/`int32_t`, no BigInts or libraries are required for that. Bitwise binary operations cause JavaScript numbers to behave like 32-bit integers, so you can write `(a + b) | 0` to make the addition behave like a C++ `int` addition.

If all you need is 64-bit integers, it's not difficult to represent them as pairs of 32-bit numbers. There are also several existing libraries that do that (just use your favorite search engine). If you don't actually need arbitrarily big integers, that may be a nice alternative.

Comment: would like to learn more about it in my particular case. Is there a way of getting in touch with you @jmrk?

Comment: @Karan You can always ask another question. I don't have time to do 1:1 consulting.

Comment: Note also that rather than stitching together two 32-bit numbers, javascript 64 bit integers can also be represented directly by [BigUint64Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigUint64Array), stored in platform byte order.  BigUint64Array is compatible with all modern browsers...